# One similar phrase but for two different intents

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es

I have two intents. Both, however, may use a common phrase of "What is the status of ...". The first intent is for Request Tickets and shall always include a Request Number which starts with REQ. For example, "what is the status of REQ0054896?". The second intent is for the status of a service, such as "What is the status of Google Mail?".

I have made a custom entity for the REQ Number which is in Dialogflow as REQ@sys.number-integer:number-interger. I have also done the training and ensuring that the intents are matched however it does not always return the correct values.

I'd like it so that whenever the REQ number is entered, it matches it to the entity and understands that the user is asking for the status of a request, rather than for a business service.

[image: Request Intent]

[image: Business Service Intent]

[image: Incorrect Intent Match]

As you can see from the above images, the phrase of "What is the status of..." is a common factor in both intents. Then the screenshot shows that a question in which a REQ number is used, it matches with the Business Service Intent.

Comment: Can you update your question to include screen shots of the two intents in question and some examples of when it is not matching as you expect?

Comment: @Prisoner I have included screenshots now to make it easier to understand!

Comment: That's very useful. Can you also provide what the Entity/Parameter definitions are for the two Intents in question? And, to clarify, is there a context defined for the "Request Business Service State"?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a simple rule-based intent classifier before the main one, in these situations when you can catch some intents with certainty can save you some headache.

I'm not aware of the details of your algorithm (data, model, ...) but clearly "What is the" part should not be important. One technique to reduce the importance of these types of words is using criteria like tf-idf as a weight function.